# Installing a module in case it is missing

Tags: python, import, cross-platform

I have a python code which uses paramiko module. By default paramiko is not installed and in order to make sure the code will always run I need to add some sort of a safe import method that tries to import the module and in case of failure will try to install it. What is the most pythonic way to achieve an equivalent code to the following one?

```
import os, importlib

def SafeImport(module):
    while True:
        try:
            module = importlib.import_module(module)
            return module
        except Exception as e:
            print module + ' is not installed, you will need root privileges to install it. ' + str(e)
            os.system('sudo yum --assumeyes install python-pip python-devel')
            os.system('sudo pip install ' + module)

paramiko = SafeImport('paramiko')
```

This is clearly not a cross platform code, it will fail on windows, mac os and even on linux distros without `yum`. In fact I can't be sure what version of python with run the script so it is possible that `importlib` won't be available to it. What is the general pythonic way to address such issues?

Comment: Probably the best solution is to create proper Python package and to list requirements inside your setup file.

Answer (score 1):

The most pythonic way of doing this is

```
import paramiko
```

This produces the following output.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named paramiko
```

Users can then make an intelligent decision on how to install it on their system. You can, of course, package your software so that `paramiko` is installed for them.

Comment: The users need to know only how to use the software, they don't care about `paramiko` or any installation procedures, they just want to use the software with minimal headache. Packaging the software with `pyinstaller` is an option I'm considering and it might work fine, but I was trying to avoid distributing binary files. Having said that I don't agree that a code that will **definitely** cause `ImportError` is truly pythonic.

Comment: @e271p314 How is a user going to install your software? Your software *definitely* shouldn't install software for users.

Comment: The way I want it to work is that the user just downloads the script and can use it immediately

Comment: @e271p314 If you expect users to do that, they will be experienced developers, and as such, can deal with installing `paramiko` themselves. I'd be pretty pissed off if something installed a module for me - at least use something like `distutils` and package it up.

Comment: Most probably they are not developers at all, just regular users.

Comment: @e271p314 Then they will struggle download and run a script that *isn't* some sort of installer.

Comment: Exactly, they want to download a working application that doesn't require any prerequisites, so I want to make any installation procedure transparent. But I do agree that an installer is a good idea, I was just wondering if I can circumvent it.